# How secure is a user in MySQL?

Tags: encryption, passwords, databases, mysql, aws

Let's say I have two databases on the same server (e.g. AWS RDS), `DB1` and `DB2`. There are two users with some restrictions, and each user is assigned to a different database. `US1` have access to `DB1`, and `US2` have access to `DB2`.

The users and their passwords are stored separately on different servers. `DB1` is used to store ciphertext, and `DB2` to store the encryption keys.

Can I be sure, in 100%, that without the passwords (ignoring bruteforcing and other attacks on the password itself), that while having access to only one of the users, an attacker won't be able to access the other database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the permissions correctly, yes, you can be sure.

To grant user `US1` select, insert, delete permissions to database `DB1` use this query:

`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON DB1.* TO 'US1'@'host';`

or for all privileges

`GRANT ALL ON DB1.* TO 'US1'@'host';`

This way `US1` can see and interact with `DB1`, while unable to interact with `DB2`.

You can test this by authenticating as user `US1` and using the query: `show databases;` via the command line or phpmyadmin. You will only see `DB1` in the results.

Comment: So basically there is no way there could be a backdoor that will allow an attacker to access `DB2` via `US1`?

Comment: Obviously there are privilege escalation bugs around, but if you keep your server up-to-date these shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you access the `DB2` server that stores encryption keys, bruteforcing becomes easier, but it does not mean instant access to the other database. In the other case, accessing ciphertext should not be a problem if the encryption algorithm is strong enough.

Comment: Yeh, but it can be a problem if you have the keys.

Comment: You don't have the keys. You only have the ciphertext in that case...